# Android Instant apps not showing

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am needing to create an instant app based on an already created application that is in the app store.

However I am trying to test the usage of instant apps, and I cannot get any to load or show on Google that have their own instant app.

I have followed this tutorial from Android Authority (http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-instant-apps-749544/) and tried it on a Google Pixel running 8.0.0 and a Nexus 6 running 7.1.1.

Both the phones have the feature enabled in settings, but when I search any of the suggested apps on Google (e.g. Wish, Buzzfeed, Vimeo etc), the instant app does not show up and it takes me directly to the play store.

Does anyone know if instant apps are temporarily disabled, or whether it's limited to a certain Android OS, or if it's due to the regionality as i'm in the UK?

Furthermore if anyone has a link for me to test that should open an instant app, that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hope this link will help you.. Link --> https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html

Comment: This is a link showing me how to make my own, I am not yet at that stage. I am just trying to open already created instant apps such as wish, buzzfeed, vimeo, stack overflow and it is not working.

Comment: UK is eligible. You can try to open https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty from Gmail.

Comment: Also, sometimes, the cache may also be weird. Perform “Clear Data” on these apps: Google Play Store, Google Play Services, Chrome.  Then.. open Play Store to make sure you’re signed back in, open Chrome and sign-in too.  Try again - let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that they work consistently when you open them from another app rather than from chrome.

@TWL suggestion of opening **buzzfeed.com/tasty** from gmail works every time for me.

Other ways of getting instant apps to load are by viewing them from twitter, for example if you search for a video on vimeo it will open up their instant app.

Comment: Yes, **buzzfeed.com/tasty** works every time for me also. But for other apps (like wish, nyt crosswords, jet etc) are not working. **Have you got any solution yet**.
How to open it as instant app instead of installed app or a web site.